# Resolve dynamic type of one property based on value of another one string property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Hi I'm not sure is it possible or not but if not possible please suggest me some alternative ways to achieve it.

I want to set a type of an object property in an interface in which the object might have any properties but must have a property named with a value of another one property in that interface. Let consider the case

```
interface ListGroupProps {
  data: {[x:string]:any} & {[valueProperty]:any};
  valueProperty:string;
}
```

Now consider an object with valid type

```
{
    data:{id:1, textValue: "hello world"},
    valueProperty: "textValue",
}
```

Here is an object with invalid type

```
{
    data:{id:1, textValue: "hello world"}, // someOtherPropertyName in not present here
    valueProperty: "someOtherPropertyName",
}
```

It would be better if possible to do without Generic types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do but you have to use generics:

```
interface ListGroupProps<K extends (string extends K ? never : keyof any)> {
    data: { [x: string]: any } & { [x in K]: any };
    valueProperty: K;
}

const x: ListGroupProps<'textValue'> = {
    data: { id: 1, textValue: "hello world" },
    valueProperty: "textValue",
} as const;

const y1: ListGroupProps<'textValue'> = {
    data: { id: 1, textValue: "hello world" },
    valueProperty: "someOtherPropertyName", // Error on `valueProperty`
};

const y2: ListGroupProps<'someOtherPropertyName'> = {
    data: { id: 1, textValue: "hello world" }, // Error on `data`.
    valueProperty: "someOtherPropertyName",
};

const y3: ListGroupProps<string> = { // Error on `string`.
    data: { id: 1, textValue: "hello world" },
    valueProperty: "someOtherPropertyName",
};
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gOJQPYCuADgAr5EYA8A0shAB6QgAmGyAFFlKAOZ2MQWbWgH5kICADdoyAFzIA1hACeeGMjghlASgB8yAN4AoZKeTM4YOPIPIA2vXldeAXXmblyAL7IAZIft6ZFBkajcNLW8AbhMzSTgAGwIIMjwiaDBleWoYryMjBDwQLGRHNEwcfGJUikoAckhGADVE5Lr9AF5DWNMLKxtg5nkARgAaZEawFqSIeQAiAAsIBIS8ZAB3PCgE5jnvUZ7keJmajKzkOcnp5LmDnzg2QuKwGIKikuVh+XQsXEJSchUBoMKatCDtZBdYxmcyWawBYBDZBjCYg66zC5LFZrTbbXb7Q7HZKnKCZeYYPAAWwgAHkwEsoCTMgA5ODU27IAD0nOQAFEoPgoMgisgAAZElLkM6ioxeV5PD4AJm+FT+1UB9Qp1LpDKZylZ1IhUMOfXhtkRI3GVzB8yxqw2Wx2ey8425fIFW2FIDFptFADpCWC9eSqbT6dA9QaILdZfL3mBkMoAMwq35VAFpKjOEA8ToBN38wVesXZnj+k1wgYW5FWtE2zHLe24p0EmES4MXLVh3VS0n6tnRu4xIA)

Comment: Thank a lot. This will be a solution to my problem. Generics is OK. I can accommodate that. Thank you.